# php.ini and php extension in TideSDK

Tags: php, php-extension, tidesdk

i have installed tideSDK 1.3 beta and TideSDK developer. i look at in TideSDK module/win32/php/ext folder and there is a php_gd2.dll file. i want to add another extension like php_mbstring, but where is php.ini,php_mbstring in TideSDK? how do it works without php.ini at now?

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, the php.ini file for my TideSDK is at /opt/php/lib

I was able to get all phpinfo for my set up by doing this:

```
<script type="text/php">
  function pinfo(){
    global $Ti;

    $fn = $Ti->Filesystem->getFile($Ti->Filesystem->getDesktopDirectory(), "phpinfo.txt");

    ob_start();
    phpinfo();
    $i = ob_get_clean();
    file_put_contents($fn, $i);

    return $i;
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = pinfo();
  document.write("<pre>" + i + "</pre>");
</script>
```

This outputs a some of the info to your app's window but you can see all of it by opening the "phpinfo.txt" file that was placed on your desktop.

From this info you should be able to find anything you need to know about the php installation used by your TideSDK.